# Adding Custom Column in Sql Server profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Requirement: Need a Client IP in Sql Trace for better monitoring of application behaviour - to prevent duplicate database calls.

Is there any Possibility of adding Customised column in Sql server profiler ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into extended events instead of using trace (assuming you are on 2012 or greater). It is the replacement for profiler. It is more flexible and consumes fewer resources on the server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx As for the question at hand, I don't think there is any way to add a custom column.

Comment: The closest thing to this is the `HostName` column. If that doesn't provide you with the information you need, Profiler can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for valuable comments @SeanLange

Comment: @JeroenMostert - HostName - Captures only where the web application got hosted [AppServer machine name got captured]... Not an exact client IP from the client..

Comment: So you're tracing the calls of a web application. That's not clear from your question. The IP address of the remote host simply isn't available to SQL Server at all, so there's no way to include it in a Profiler trace (or an extended event session, for that matter). You're better off turning on/adding tracing in the web application itself. If your application has no built in facilities, however, this is anything but easy, as it involves mucking around with ETW.

Comment: The closest I can think of to sending identifying information on through to the sql trace is to create multiple database logins for your test and output the login name in the trace. It would be very limiting for multiple uses however, you could switch connection strings in your application based on something like a a user name.

Comment: I believe I will go with Webapplication trace to capture the client details... Thanks for your suggestion @JeroenMostert